# Return function in createAsyncThunk() return second parameter as [object][object] describing errors

Tags: javascript, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Why is the second parameter of the Async function in the createAscynThunk() middleware returns an object while a string is expected?

Code from where I dispatch

```js
  const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    console.log(date, code); // [date, code]
    dispatch(fetchCurrencyByCodeLatestInSpecificDate(date, code));
  };
```

In the code above `date` and `code` variables return correctly when I log them to the console.

In my createAsyncThunk middleware

```js
export const fetchCurrencyByCodeLatestInSpecificDate = createAsyncThunk(
  FETCH_CURRENCIES_BY_CURRENCY_CODE__IN_SPECIIC_DATE,
  async (date, code) => {
    console.log(date, code); /* the date ouput result is correct but code returns an object with data = 
    {extra: undefined, requestId: 'QJrKF6PbWlQQJei9qIpK0', signal: AbortSignal, dispatch: ƒ, getState: ƒ, …}
    dispatch: ƒ dispatch()
    extra: undefined
    fulfillWithValue: ƒ (value, meta)
    getState: ƒ i()
    rejectWithValue: ƒ (value, meta)
    requestId: "QJrKF6PbWlQQJei9qIpK0"
    signal: AbortSignal {aborted: false, reason: undefined, onabort: null}
    } */
    const response = await fetch(`${CURRENCIES_BASE_API_URL}/${date}/currencies/${code}.json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  },
);
```

The return values in the console.

[[object][object] describing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYEQ8.png)

I tried by exchanging the parameters in the async function and when I did that the `date` parameter the was returning correctly return the same error.

Answer (score 0):

createAsyncThunk() accept two parameters that is action `type` and a `payloadCreater`.

The payloadCreater accepts two arguments. The `arg` that was passed to the thunk action creator when it was dispatched and the `thunkApi` that returns an object containing all of the parameters that are normally passed to a Redux thunk function.

The `arg`: This is useful for passing in values like item IDs that may be needed as part of the request like what I what to do in the code above but If I need to pass in multiple values, I have to pass them together in an object when you dispatch the thunk, like

```js
const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const date = e.target.value;
    dispatch(fetchCurrencyByCodeLatestInSpecificDate({ date, code }));
  };
```

them createAsyncThunk() funtion will be

```js
export const fetchCurrencyByCodeLatestInSpecificDate = createAsyncThunk(
  FETCH_CURRENCIES_BY_CURRENCY_CODE__IN_SPECIIC_DATE,
  async (dateCodeObj) => {
    console.log(dateCodeObj);
    const response = await fetch(`${CURRENCIES_BASE_API_URL}/${dateCodeObj.date}/currencies/${dateCodeObj.code}.json`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  },
);
```

Read more about createAsyncThuck() payloadCreator which is a callback function at [payloadcreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)